# xrandr long delay (completely reproduceable!)

Tags: screen, xrandr

I'm finding that when I do "`xrandr --output eDP-1 --reflect xy`" it seems instantaneous, but when I then do "`xrandr --output eDP-1 --reflect normal`" (to put it back) there's a delay of something like three seconds (during which time the screen is black).  If the screen is already in normal mode, the latter command does not have a delay.  Same results if I do it to my external monitor (HDMI-1) instead of to the laptop screen (eDP-1) (maybe more like five seconds instead of three in that case?).

Why would this be, and is some way to flip the screen without a long delay?  Same thing with "--rotate inverted" followed by "--rotate normal".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  It should be asked on another SE site.  Probably https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (You might even get an answer there ...)